# For a HTTP server that supports range requests, can server return less bytes than requested?

Tags: http, partial

I have read RFC 7233 regarding HTTP range requests and despite lots of searching something which is not clear to me is this:

Let's say there is a file that is 10Gb in size that the client is requesting, and the client specifies a Range header of:

Range: 0-

This would put an onus on the server to return the whole 10GB file would it not?

Therefore, is the server free to downscale the range request and return less bytes than requested. In the above example, could is return the first 100MB instead of the whole 10GB, with a 206 response code (assuming the Content-Range defines the correct 0-99999999 range of course).

The RFC explicitly allows for multiple ranges to be consolidated into a single range if the "gaps" between ranges are close enough together that it makes it more economical to coalesce the ranges together -- the point being that the RFC already allows some "degree of freedom" in interpreting the ranges for reasons such as economy or efficiency, so I'm wondering if returning a smaller range would be permitted for similar reasons.

Comment: Hi ! Did you find a response to that question ? I'm looking for the same info. Thanks !